# Google Maps and PDF reader API throws UnSupported URL error when Migrating from UIWebView To WKWebView

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

Since Apple deprecated UIWebView and supports WKWebView, we updated the iOS version to 6.0.0 and removed **cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine** plugin that was no longer supported.

After the iOS upgrade google map and pdf API calls stopped working and throws **unsupported URL error**.

We are using **cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 4.0.0** to call Google Map and PDF reader APIs.  Below is the code snippet of InAppBrowser to call google Map URL.

```
$scope.openMap = function(url) {
  options='location=no,toolbar=yes';
  cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options);
  return false;
}
```

[Unsupported URL Error for Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqdN4.png)
Below are the plugins installed and platform details:

Installed platforms:

```
  android 7.1.4

  browser 5.0.4

  ios 6.1.0
```

[Plugin details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i1en.png)

Example error from XCode, it seems the issue is WkWebView attempting to redirect to an ios map URL scheme:

```
2020-12-28 10:08:46.801102-0500 <AppName>[458:34098] webView:didFailProvisionalNavigation - 0: Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)
```